# Como puedo recorrer un observable con datos obtenidos de firebase

Tags: firebase, angularjs-2.0, ionic2

Necesito recorrer un *observable* obtenido desde firebase, donde comparo un `id`, para poder crear un **array** con los datos que pertenezcan a este `id`.

```
 '  import { Component } from '@angular/core';

   import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
 //import { DaggService } from '../../providers/dagg-service';
  import { FirebaseListObservable, AngularFireDatabase  } from 'angularfire2';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
  import 'rxjs/Rx';


@Component({
   selector: 'page-home',
   templateUrl: 'home.html'/*,
  providers:[ DaggService ]*/
})
 export class HomePage {

 regiones: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
 provincias: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
 ciudades: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

/*public regiones: any;
public provincias: any;
public ciudades: any;*/


 constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        ///public ds: DaggService//,
        public alertCtrl: AlertController,
        public database: AngularFireDatabase
        ) {
            /*this.regiones = [];
            this.provincias = [];
            this.ciudades = [];*/

            // AQUÍ EXTRAIGO LOS DATOS 
            this.regiones = this.database.list('/regiones');
            this.provincias = this.database.list('/provincias');
            this.ciudades = this.database.list('/ciudades');
            console.log(this.regiones)
        }
 getCiudades(provincia){

    console.log(provincia)

}
ionViewDidLoad(){


} 



}
 '
```

Según el `id` obtenido, `ion-select` recorre el *observable* de las ciudades, el cual contiene: **IDCIUDAD**, **NOMBRECIUDAD** e **IDPROVINCIA**, para luego comparar el **IDPROVINCIA* devuelto por el `ion-select` con el del *observable* y crear un array de ciudades dependiendo del ID de las provincias.

Comment: alguien qu me ayude pliss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quería escribirte un comentario en lugar de una respuesta, pero el sistema me pide tener mínimo 50 puntos para hacerlo.

Para poder obtener los datos de un Observable necesitas subscribirte a ellos. Por tanto, yo haría lo siguiente:

`

```
export class HomePage {

public regiones: any = [];
public provincias: any = [];
public ciudades: any = [];


 constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        ///public ds: DaggService//,
        public alertCtrl: AlertController,
        public database: AngularFireDatabase
        ) {
            // AQUÍ EXTRAIGO LOS DATOS 
            this.database.list('/regiones').subscribe( 
                regiones => this.regiones = regiones,
                error => console.log(error)
            );
            this.database.list('/provincias').subscribe( 
                provincias => this.provincias = provincias,
                error => console.log(error)
            );
            this.database.list('/ciudades').subscribe( 
                ciudades => this.ciudades = ciudades,
                error => console.log(error)
            );
            console.log(this.regiones)
        }
 getCiudades(provincia){

    this.ciudades.foreach( ciudad =>{
         //Aquí insertas el código de comparación que necesites
    });

}
ionViewDidLoad(){


}
```

` 
Espero que te sirva.

Comment: gracias,ya lo solucione, casi de la misma manera.